# Epsilon-delta proof final goal

Tags: proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

Is the final goal of the scratch work in an Epsilon-delta proof to find a delta that is a function of Epsilon?

Comment: Yes, this is basically correct.

Comment: In some sense, yes. Your goal is to find a delta based on the given epsilon so that the rest of the argument will work and you can prove what is to be proved. The work required to find that delta is often omitted from the final argument (delta is merely declared to be something that suffices and then the argument proceeds from there). I think it would be better pedagogical practice to include the derivation of delta that will suffice as a matter of providing explanation of how to do that in general.